# Move Object to Destination Smoothly Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying the whole day to move an object from **point A** to **point B** smoothly, so I tried **Lerp**, **MoveTowards** and **SmoothDamp** but every time the object just disappear from point A and appear on point B instantly!

I tried every solution that I found in internet but I got the same result.

Can you please save my life and help me to solve that?

Here's the codes I've tried:

```
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.localPosition, Destination, ref velocity, Speed);
```

---

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, Destination, Speed);
```

---

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, Destination, Speed);
```

---

And more...

Comment: You need to update its position every frame, not just once

Comment: What is your speed? It should change each frame starting from 0 to 1...

Comment: What is the value of the speed? Please share your complete code.

Comment: I tried several value for the speed, I tried Big values like 1000 or 100 and I tried Small values like 5 or 1 or 0.5 also, and I tried them with and without time.deltatime

Comment: @Taik Did you add the code in `Update` function?

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi Yes in Update method, I tried it also in FixedUpdate

Answer (score 5):

You need to continuously update the position using Lerp.  You could do this using a coroutine as follows (assuming Origin and Destination are defined positions):

```
public IEnumerator moveObject() {
    float totalMovementTime = 5f; //the amount of time you want the movement to take
    float currentMovementTime = 0f;//The amount of time that has passed
    while (Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, Destination) > 0) {
        currentMovementTime += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(Origin, Destination, currentMovementTime / totalMovementTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

You would call this coroutine with:

```
StartCoroutine(moveObject());
```

Comment: Great but it's working just for the first movement! in the next movements it didn't work properly!!

Comment: Can you please tell me why it's working just for the first time?

Comment: Seems to be working for me.  Are you using StartCoroutine instead of just calling the method?  Maybe you can share more of your code.

Comment: Make sure your Lerp command is the same as mine, with current time / total time.  Looks like you may be confusing this field with speed, but it is actually meant to be the time that is passed divided by the total time the movement is meant to go on for.  If you put a single number in this field, the object will stay at this one position.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I mean that I have 4 coroutines in my code, one for movement forward and another for backward, right and left. And when the swipe is up the object move forward, when the swipe is left the object move to the left etc... on each swipe I call the appropriate coroutine with the StartCoroutine. But when I play the game, the first swipe work properly, but in the second one the object didn't reach the destination point, and the third one also and it have a weird movement.

Comment: A bit late now but this code 'can' only run once if the >0 condition never reaches zero but is an tiny value so gets stuck in the loop. make the condition > 0.002f and after the loop set the position to the destination position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SmoothMove : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 0.01f;
    private Vector3 destination;

    void Start()
    {
        destination = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, destination, speed)
    }

    void SetDestination(Vector3 newPos)
    {
        destination = newPos;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: It's not working, the object move just a little bit, maybe 1 pixel and it stops.

Comment: This is not the correct usage of Lerp and will not work.  Lerp is supposed to take the arguments for origin, destination, some value from 0 to 1 to represent where the object is, with 0 being origin and 1 being destination.  This code also has destination being set to the transforms current position at start, which doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @DanWahl Thanks for your comment. Yes, this is not the correct usage of `Lerp`. It's just a very simple code to move smoothly from `source` to `destination`.